# Draw custom view inside custom view

Tags: android, tree, kotlin, android-view, android-custom-view

I am working on a custom view, `TreeView`, which would display a tree given a root node. I am using the Kotlin language.

Here's what part of it looks like at the moment:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    drawNodeAndChildren(canvas, rootNode)
}

/**
 * Draws a representation of a node and its children onto the canvas.
 * ...
 */
private fun drawNodeAndChildren(canvas: Canvas, node: TreeNode<Person>, ...): Int {
    ...

    // Calculate coordinates of rect
    val top = ...
    val bottom = ...
    val left = ...
    val right = ...

    // Draw node representation
    val rect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
    canvas.drawRect(rect, nodePaint)

    // Draw line to connect to parent
    ...

    // Repeat for children
    ...
}
```

This works successfully, and I am able to produce a visual tree with rectangles representing nodes and lines between parents and children.

However, I want to be able to display an image and text of the person. I have written a compound view called `PersonView` which is able to do this given a `Person` object. Ideally, in the future, the user would be able to click on these `PersonView`s in the `TreeView` to trigger an action.

So essentially, instead of rectangles, `PersonView`s would be drawn.

I have tried creating the view programmatically and setting its layout params like so:

```
    ...

    val personView = PersonView(context).apply { person = node.data }
    val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            (right - left).toInt(), // width
            (bottom - top).toInt() // height
    )
    personView.layoutParams = layoutParams
    personView.x = left
    personView.y = top
    personView.draw(canvas)
    ...
```

I've also tried:

```
    ...

    val personView = PersonView(context).apply { person = node.data }
    personView.layout(left.toInt(), top.toInt(), right.toInt(), bottom.toInt())
    personView.draw(canvas)
    ...
```

In both cases, nothing is drawn instead of the rectangles - it's as if the two code samples above has no effect.

*N.B. the lines between where the rectangles would be (i.e. connections between nodes) is drawn, and this part of the code has not been altered.*

So my question is **how do I draw a custom view inside another custom view** so that I can get the effect I have described?

Comment: I don't know much about custom view. But I think you may try to use `addView(View)` and let the child view to do the drawing itself.

Comment: @BakaWaii Yes, I am aware that I could use `addView` but then I would need to extend `ViewGroup` instead of `View`. How exactly would my custom view implementation differ if I extended `ViewGroup` instead? Thanks.

Comment: Since you aren't adding your PersonView as a child to your custom view, I think what you're missing is calling the measure method on PersonView.